# Adding list of records Failed in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, mstest

I tried to add entities to the database with Entity Framework, but it failed. Here is the source code that is responsible for adding a list of entities to the database:

```
public class EfUserPermissionRepository : IUserPermissionDal
{

    private readonly EfDbContext _context;

    public EfUserPermissionRepository(EfDbContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(typeof(EfDbContext).ToString());

        this._context = context;
    } 

    //It adds USERPERMISSION list to database. 
    public void Add(List<USERPERMISSION> entities)
    {

        try
        {
            if (entities == null || !entities.Any())
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            foreach (USERPERMISSION value in entities)
            {

                if (value == null)
                    continue;

                this._context.USERPERMISSION.Add(value);
            }

            this._context.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }

    }

    public USERPERMISSION Add(USERPERMISSION entity)
    {
        _context.USERPERMISSION.Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return entity;
    }

}
```

I have a class named USERPERMISSION. It has two foreign key relations with the other class named USER and PAGE. Here is the content of the USERPERMISSION class:

```
[Table("USERPERMISSION")]
public class USERPERMISSION
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("USER")]
    public int USERID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PAGE")]
    public int PAGEID { get; set; }
    public int? ADD { get; set; }
    public int? EDIT { get; set; }
    public int? DELETE { get; set; }
    public int? READ { get; set; }
    public int? LIST { get; set; }
    public int? REPORT { get; set; }
    public int? PUBLISH { get; set; }
    public int? CONFIRM { get; set; }
    public int ACTIVE { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string CODE { get; set; }

    public virtual USER USER { get; set; }
    public virtual PAGE PAGE { get; set; }

}
```

In order to test the *Add* method defined in *EfUserPermissionRepository*, I devised a test code. I get all USERPERMISSION of user 1 and copy it to user 2. Currently, user 1 has 26 user permissions, whereas user 2 has not got any USERPERMISSION. My intention is to copy all USERPERMISSION lists of user 1 to user 2 and save them to the database.  Here is the test code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using PROJECT.Tests.Soyut;
using PROJECT.Entity.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace PROJECT.Tests
{
[TestClass]
public class UserPermissionManagerTest : TestBase
{

    private int UserId1 { get; set; }

    private USER User2 { get; set; }
    
    private List<USERPERMISSION> UserPermissionList1 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The procedure where the <code>Add</code> procedure was tested against user 2.        
    /// 
    /// It is hoped that it will be successful.
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void USERPERMISSIONAdd_001()
    {

        //’UserPermissionManageri’ is a Business layer component that emerges from TestBase.
        List<USERPERMISSION> list = UserPermissionManageri.Add(UserPermissionList1);
        
        Assert.IsNotNull(list);

        Assert.AreEqual(true, list.Any());


    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestClassInitialize()
    {
        UserId1 = 1;                       

        //’UserManageri’ is a Business layer component that emerges from TestBase.
        User2 = UserManageri.Get(2);

        Assert.IsNotNull(User2);
        
        //Creates a new list by getting all user permission list of user 1 to user 2.
        UserPermissionList1 = this.CopyUserPermissionList(UserId1, User2);

        Assert.IsNotNull(UserPermissionList1);

        Assert.AreEqual(true, UserPermissionList1.Any());

    }

    private List<USERPERMISSION> CopyUserPermissionList(int sourceUserId, USER targetUserToCopy)
    {

        //getting all user permission list of the sourceUserId. 
        List<USERPERMISSION> list = UserPermissionManageri.List(p => p.USERID == sourceUserId);

        //ensure that the list is not null.
        Assert.IsNotNull(list);

        //ensure that the list has a value. 
        Assert.AreEqual(true, list.Any());

        List<USERPERMISSION> copyList = new List<USERPERMISSION>();

        //copying the list to the copylist 
        foreach (USERPERMISSION value in list)
        {
            if (value == null)
                continue;

            copyList.Add(new USERPERMISSION()
            {
                USERID = value.USERID,
                PAGEID = value.PAGEID,
                ADD = value.ADD,
                EDIT = value.EDIT,
                DELETE = value.DELETE,
                READ = value.READ,
                LIST = value.LIST,
                REPORT = value.REPORT,
                PUBLISH = value.PUBLISH,
                CONFIRM = value.CONFIRM,
                ACTIVE = value.ACTIVE,
                CODE = value.CODE,
                USER = value.USER,
                PAGE = value.PAGE,
                ID = 0
            });

        }

        //assigning targetUserToCopy to all elements of copyList 
        foreach (USERPERMISSION permission in copyList)
        {
            if (permission == null)
                continue;

            permission.USER = targetUserToCopy;
            permission.USERID = targetUserToCopy.ID; 
        }

        //returning the copylist.
        return copyList;

    }

   
}
}
```

USERPERMISSIONAdd_001 runs successfully, that is, test function is green when I run it; however, it does not make any changes in the database. Where am I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters, the "repository" class serves no purpose, it just aliases the DbContext `AddRange` and `Add` methods. A DbSet already is a single-entity Repository, a DbContext already is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work. The use of `SaveChanges in `EfUsers...Add` is a *major* bug and breaks the Unit-of-Work pattern. `SaveChanges` is used to *commit* all pending changes and will perform any pending UPDATE and DELETEs as well. To rollback, just don't call it and let the DbContext instance get disposed.

Comment: How did you determine that nothing is saved? The unit test doesn't use EF or `EfUserPermissionRepository` at all

Comment: Thank you for your criticism. I will make changes accordingly. **UserPermissionManageri** utilizes the **EfUserPermissionRepository** , because the query of data is successful in test class. I determine that nothing is saved by running this SQL command "SELECT ID, USERID, PAGEID, "ADD", EDIT, "DELETE", READ, LIST, REPORT, PUBLISH, CONFIRM, ACTIVE, CODE FROM PROJECT.USERPERMISSION where userid = 2"

Comment: It's not criticism. Almost 90% of EF questions every day show this well-known bug, asking the same questions. Right now the question contains no EF code and nothing that shows there's a problem. There's nothing that tries to call `SaveChanges` or even `...Repository`, nothing that tries to load that back. For all one knows, you may be connecting to the wrong database, or trying to use the in-memory provider, or SQLite in in-memory mode

Comment: To troubleshoot this, start by isolating the problem. Create a new test using *only* the `EfDbContext` class, no wrappers.  Instead of using SQLite or LocalDB, use eg SQL Server Express and a test database (no `AttachDbFilename`), to ensure you're always connecting to the correct DB. Create a *simple* test that just calls `context.AddRange(someObjects); context.SaveChanges();`. Do the new items appear?

Comment: I have just tried the solution you have proposed, and I am getting the error "Project.Tests.Somut.BusinessLayer.UserPermissionManagerTest.USERPERMISSIONAdd_001 threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."
Your proposition is a great step forward to resolve the issue. It is a great idea to isolate the DbContext from business layer component.

Comment: `multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker` are you using multiple DbContexts? You wouldn't get this error if you used conventional EF Core code. I repeat, a DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a disconnected "transaction" object. It doesn't even open a connection to the database until you call `SaveChanges`. There's no reason to have more than one in any use case. The same DbContext that loads data at the start of the operation should be used to save the modifications

Comment: Yes, I was using multiple DbContext. I managed to make it one. I made it one, and I ran it with pure DbContext, I was using AddRange() and I was calling SaveChanges(), however, it still does not save the records to the database. I try to resolve it. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) pointed out, I start by isolating the problem. I discard the *UserPermissionManageri* in test *UserPermissionManagerTest* and create a new *DbContext* in *UserPermissionManagerTest*.  Test class looks like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using PROJECT.Tests.Soyut;
using PROJECT.Entity.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PROJECT.Dal.Concrete.EntityFramework;

namespace PROJECT.Tests.Concrete.BusinessLayer
{
  [TestClass]
  public class UserPermissionManagerTest : TestBase
  {

    private int UserId1 { get; set; }

    private USER User2 { get; set; }
    
    private List<USERPERMISSION> UserPermissionList1 { get; set; }
    
    private static EfDbContext EfDbContexti { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The procedure where the <code>Add</code> procedure was tested against user 1665.        
    /// 
    /// It is hoped that it will be successful.
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void USERPERMISSIONAdd_001()
    {

        IEnumerable<USERPERMISSION> list = EfDbContexti.USERPERMISSION.AddRange(UserPermissionList1);

        EfDbContexti.SaveChanges();

        Assert.IsNotNull(list);

        Assert.AreEqual(true, list.Any());

    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestClassInitialize()
    { 

        UserId1 = 17;

        EfDbContexti = new EfDbContext();

        User2 = EfDbContexti.USER.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == 1665);
        
        //User2 = UserManageri.Get(1665);

        Assert.IsNotNull(User2);
        
        //Creates a new list by getting all user permission list of user 17 to user 1665
        UserPermissionList1 = this.CopyUserPermissionList(UserId1, User2);

        Assert.IsNotNull(UserPermissionList1);

        Assert.AreEqual(true, UserPermissionList1.Any());

    }
    
    [ClassCleanup]
    public static void TestClassCleanup()
    {

        if (EfDbContexti != null)
        {
            EfDbContexti.SaveChanges();
            EfDbContexti.Dispose();
            EfDbContexti = null;
        }
    }

    private List<USERPERMISSION> CopyUserPermissionList(int sourceUserId, USER targetUserToCopy)
    {

        //getting all user permission list of the sourceUserId. 
        
        IQueryable< USERPERMISSION> iqueryable =  EfDbContexti.USERPERMISSION.Where(p => p.USERID == sourceUserId);

        Assert.IsNotNull(iqueryable);

        List<USERPERMISSION> list = iqueryable.ToList();

        //ensure that list is not null.
        Assert.IsNotNull(list);

        //ensure that list has a value. 
        Assert.AreEqual(true, list.Any());

        List<USERPERMISSION> copyList = new List<USERPERMISSION>();

        //copying the list to copylist 
        foreach (USERPERMISSION value in list)
        {
            if (value == null)
                continue;

            copyList.Add(new USERPERMISSION()
            {
                USERID = value.USERID,
                PAGEID = value.PAGEID,
                ADD = value.ADD,
                EDIT = value.EDIT,
                DELETE = value.DELETE,
                READ = value.READ,
                LIST = value.LIST,
                REPORT = value.REPORT,
                PUBLISH = value.PUBLISH,
                CONFIRM = value.CONFIRM,
                ACTIVE = value.ACTIVE,
                CODE = value.CODE,
                USER = value.USER,
                PAGE = value.PAGE,
                ID = 0
            });

        }

        //assigning targetUserToCopy to all elements of copyList 
        foreach (USERPERMISSION permission in copyList)
        {
            if (permission == null)
                continue;

            permission.USER = targetUserToCopy;
            permission.USERID = targetUserToCopy.ID; 
        }

        //returning the copylist.
        return copyList;

    }

   
}
```

}

Since *TestBase* has another independent *DbContext* variable, this situation causes the exception below:

> Entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
> IEntityChangeTracker. while adding related objects to entity in Entity
> Framework.

When I remove the inheritance between *UserPermissionManagerTest* and *TestBase* the problem has disappeared and relevant records are successfully saved to the database.